# How to select text from DataTable object in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a Bokeh DataTable object. I am dynamically updating it using an incoming stream of data. At some point of time I would like to select (using mouse) a particular cell and copy its value (to another text-box). However, I am unable to copy the text. Is there any attribute in DataTable that can be used to do that, or is there any other workaround.

```
data = dict(x=[], y=[])
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
columns = [
            TableColumn(field="x", title="ID"),
            TableColumn(field="y", title="Count"),
          ]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

demo_data = {}
demo_data['x'] = ["9985", "5106", "1218", "3427",
                  "2642", "2769", "3410", "9220",
                  "1298", "6562"]
demo_data['y'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote and external data, if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `editable` attribute to `DataTable` like:

```
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280, editable=True)
```